# How does the label in an ADRP instruction work in arm64?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, instructions

Im trying to figure out how ADRP works. I have this line of code:

`0x100595c74 <+0>:  adrp   x17, 13159`

My initial understanding of ADRP is that the program adds `0x100595c74` with an integer `13159` then makes the 12 lowest bits all 0 before storing this value into register `x17`

```
13159 = 0x3367
0x100595c74 + 0x3367 = 0x100598FDB

//Zeroing out the 12 lowest bits
0x100598FDB --> 0x100598000
```

Based on my calculations, `0x100598000` should be the value stored in `x17`

However, the value in the register is a total different number

```
(lldb) register read x17
     x17 = 0x00000001038fc000
```

I did some research and found some information.

From the arm64 [documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-General-Instructions/ADRP), they explain the syntax of adrp64 as follows:

```
ADRP  Xd, label
```

Where:

`Xd` is the 64-bit name of the general-purpose destination register, in the range 0 to 31.

`label` is the program label whose 4KB page address is to be calculated. An offset from the page address of this instruction, in the range ±4GB.

So, what is a program label? How do I calculate the actual value that is stored in the register?
If the integer `13159` is an offset from the page address of this instruction, how do I find the page address?

Comment: A label is just an address.  While `adrp` adds an offset to the program counter, the operand is the resulting address, not the offset you add to get to that address.  A label is just a symbolic name for an address; wherever you can use a label, you can also directly use an address.

Comment: A label is like `foo:` in your asm source.  Or any other way of defining a symbol, like GAS `.set`.  Or it could be a symbol that's only defined in another object file, e.g. built with `foo:`  ; `.global foo` which you just reference from other files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your disassembler seems to be providing the operand in the raw form, how it is encoded in the instruction which is already page granular. You need to add the 12 trailing zero bits. Thus the calculation should look more like `0x100595c74 + 0x3367000 = 0x1038fcc74` which will give the expected `0x1038fc000` page address.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a setting in lldb that changes how it is encoded?